# May U.S. Companies Simultaneously Issue Stock Domestically and Abroad?

Tags: united-states, stocks, regulation, foreign

According to the SEC webpage on [International Investing](https://www.sec.gov/reportspubs/investor-publications/investorpubsininvesthtm.html), "Some foreign companies list their securities in multiple markets, which may include U.S. markets." The example given regards Canadian stocks that trade both in Canadian markets and in U.S. markets.

If some foreign companies' stocks are trading both in their local market and in U.S. markets, are U.S. companies allowed to engage in the same practice? In other words, does U.S. law allow for a U.S.-based company to issue stock both on a U.S. market and in a foreign country?

Comment: Is the question about stock being simultaneously *listed* (trading occurs in both places during overlapping time periods) or simultaneously *issued* (a *new offering* occurs the *same day* in both places)?

Comment: @nanoman my curiosity was about simultaneous listing, not simultaneous issuing.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they may issue both domestic and foreign stocks simultaneously. The reason being, the United States government forbids the transference of shares of U.S. companies to foreign countries. However, this rule does not apply to stocks of foreign companies.
Companies can issue shares in foreign stock markets. There are no restrictions on foreign ownership of the shares of United States companies, except for those that are listed on the New York Stock Exchange or Nasdaq Stock Market. These companies may not sell their shares to foreign investors to the extent that they would own more than 25% of the shares of the company.

Comment: "The United States government forbids the transference of shares of U.S. companies to foreign countries" — Could you provide references for this?